# Quick sort implementation issue, array is sorted but it doesn't exit the recursive break condition

Tags: java, quicksort

I've implemented the quick sort algorithm below, the array gets sorted but it doesn't exit the recursive loop. Can someone analyze my quick sort algorithm below and check what am I'm doing wrong?

Please see my code below:

```
    package sort;

    import java.util.Arrays;

    public class QuickSort {

       public int array[];

       public void sort(int[] inputArr) {

           if (inputArr == null || inputArr.length == 0) {
               return;
           }
           this.array = inputArr;
           quickSort(0, this.array.length);
       }

        private void quickSort(int low, int high) 
         { 
             if (low < high) 
             {                  
                 int j = partition(low, high); 
                 quickSort(low, j); 
                 quickSort(j+1, high); 
             } 
         } 

       private int partition(int low, int high) { 
           int pivot = this.array[low];
           int i = low;
           int j = high;
           while (i<j) {
               do {
                   i++;
               } while (this.array[i] <= pivot);

               do {
                   j--;            
               } while (this.array[j] > pivot);
           }
           swap(low,j);
           return j;
       }

       private void swap(int i, int j) {
           int temp = this.array[i];
           this.array[i] = this.array[j];
           this.array[j] = temp;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Have you done any work so far to try to figure out the problem? Did you use a debugger, or at least mentally run the code to see if it behaves as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

The Hoare partition scheme should look like this or similar (use middle value for pivot):

```
       private int partition(int low, int high) { 
           int pivot = this.array[low+(high-low)/2];
           int i = low-1;
           int j = high+1;
           while (true) {
               while (this.array[++i] < pivot);   // not <=
               while (this.array[--j] > pivot);
               if(i >= j)
                   return j;
               swap(i,j);
           }
       }
```